# orders of maximal abelian subgroups

Tags: gr.group-theory, algebraic-groups, finite-groups

What are the orders of maximal abelian subgroups of the simple groups $F_4(q)$ and $C_4(q)$, where $F_4(q)$ is an exceptional group and $C_4(q)$ is a symplectic group?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a finite group $G$, denote the maximum of the orders of its Abelian subgroups by $a(G)$. Then we have, for $G=F_4(q)$ and $q$ even,
$$
q^{11}\le a(G)\le q^{17},
$$
and for $G=F_4(q)$, $q$ odd,
$$
q^{9}\le a(G)\le q^{14}.
$$
For $G=C_n(q)$ we have, for $n\neq 2$, 
$$
a(G)=q^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}.
$$
For a reference, see the paper *Maximal Orders of Abelian Subgroups
in Finite Chevalley Groups* by E. P. Vdovin, published in $2001$; in particular table $2$.

Comment: The paper itself is freely available online in Russian (but the English translation may require a library subscription): http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml? wshow=paper&jrnid=mzm&paperid=521&option_lang=eng But in any case, it seems tricky in some cases to get a precise value for $a(G)$, or a description of such subgroups in terms of the Lie theory data.

Comment: I see. It is translated in the Mathematical Notes (which might require a library subscription), see [here](http://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Flink.springer.com%2Fcontent%2Fpdf%2F10.1023%2FA%3A1010256129959.pdf&ei=SXSIVIPxHYPuPLy-gagG&usg=AFQjCNEPG_Pa4GwD3F5kBQZ8LRim1k9-rQ&bvm=bv.81456516,d.ZWU).